# Errors after lodash upgrade

Tags: angularjs, typescript, types, lodash, restangular

I upgraded lodash library from (v 2.4.1 to 4.17.15) and types/lodash(v 3.10.1 to 4.14.136) for an Angular JS project. I'm getting error for _.find after upgrade.
Error statement

> :Argument of type '{ 'Id': any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ListIteratorTypeGuard<{}, IdModel>'.

```
this.search = _.find<{}, IdModel>(this.Idlist, {'Id': Id});
```

How can we convert it to ListIteratorTypeGuard? 
I'm not to find any solution. Kindly help if anyone knows how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enforce partial check of shorthand object, this should help.

`type IdModel = { 
            id: number,
            foo: string
        };
        const list: Array<IdModel> = [{ id: 1, foo: 'test'}];
        find<IdModel>(list, { id: 1});`

But most of the time you shouldn't specify generic params and use default inferred params instead

Comment: How to convert the argument to ListIteratorTypeGuard? What is the mistake in my code ?

Comment: Hello, there is no mistake in yours code, by explicit setting generic parameter, like you did it, you had chosen one of the find function types (there are let say 10-15 of them), which expect iterator function as second parameter. Just use find<IdModel> and you should be fine